# File download from S3 (PDF/Jpg/Doc) and view on UI without downloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I have uploaded files (Docx, PDF, JPG) on S3 and I want to fetch the file from S3 and render it on webpage without downloading the content.

```
Index.js
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var btoa = require('btoa');
    AWS.config.update(
      {
          accessKeyId: "accessKeyId",
           secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey"
      }
    );
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.getObject(
      { Bucket: "bucket", Key: "test.PDF" },
      function (error, data) {
        if (error != null) {
          console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
        } else {
            var Base64 = require('js-base64').Base64;
            var b = Base64.encode(data.Body);
            var fileToView = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + b;
            res.render('index', { title: '' , pdfVal: fileToView });
        }
      }
    );

index.ejs

   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1Welcome <%= title %></h1>
    <a href="<%= pdfVal %>"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to render the PDF or any file type to view it on page without downloading it from Amazon S3.

I am not able to view the file even after appending content type to the byte.
I tried to follow few stack overflow questions as well but it didn't help.Can someone help me with this? or a link to previous Stackoverflow questions will help too.

Comment: you will have to download it in some fashion to view it.

Comment: @DanielA.White There is a way to render I believe by using base64 encoding and appending content type. But that too is not working for some reason.

Comment: Image should be fine, but I don't think you can render PDF, docx etc files on webpage without some libraries. For instance, you probably need pdf.js to render PDF file.

Comment: @RDoonds, Doesn't matter.  you still need to have a link to the content in order to display it, or have access to pre-computed base64 equivalency.  PDF and other files will have to have viewer libs, as mentioned above